# English expressions for exam : Document synthesis

Tags: word-choice, expressions

In a few days I will pass an English exam (Document synthesis) and I would like to know if there exist some little known English (UK please) expressions that can be placed in the introduction and the Jury might enjoy?

Moreover, How to introduce a good problematic?

I, actually, say something like that :

These four documents extracted from [...] leads to the following reflection:

Is there a better way ?

Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: To answer your specific question: "These four excerpts from [...] lead to the following conclusion:" is better.  Excerpts are pieces of documents that are extracted from them.  There are four of them, so "leads" is wrong.  If you are proving a point, the excerpts lead to a conclusion, not a reflection.  However, if the excerpts do not prove your point, but simply give rise to an idea, say that they "give rise to this idea."

Comment: Dude.  Your English in the question has enough small errors, that I think you should be honing your usage and not worrying about what we might call extra credit.  In addition to BobRodes' comments: second **and** in the 1st sentence is poor; you have both an erroneously capitalized word and a grammar problem in your 2nd sentence; in your 3rd sentence the **this** should be a **that**; there should never be space between the last word and terminal punctuation of a sentence, as in your 5th; and your last sentence has no punctuation at all.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally a very bad idea to set a goal of using expressions because someone might enjoy them, and this is especially true in an exam setting.  Juries are usually filled with people who are particularly unimpressed with attempts to impress them.

It is much better to write with the idea of making yourself understood in the most precise and most concise way possible.  Write down your ideas, and then go back over them and find ways to make them more precise and more concise.  You will lose points for being ambiguous and for rambling.  You will certainly lose points for putting in expressions simply because you have calculated that they will please the jury.

Again, then, work out what you want to say, and concentrate on saying it in a manner that it can be understood with a minimum of effort on the part of the reader.

Comment: You are very welcome.  If you have questions about the best way to say something specific, please post them.

Comment: So you are saying, "*then, work out what you want to say, and concentrate on saying it in a manner that it can be understood with a minimum of effort on the part of the reader.*" is what you've calculated will please the jury? ;-)